# C++: How to return an alias defined in a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, alias

So I've got template class (abbreviated) like:

```
template <typename keyT, typename valueT>
class hashMap {
public:
    using dataT = pair<keyT,valueT>;
    using maybeT = optional<dataT>;
    maybeT notFound = optional<dataT> ();
    maybeT find(keyT &v);
    <snip>
};
```

When I try to define find(), I have

```
template <typename keyT, typename valueT>
hashMap::maybeT hashMap<keyT,valueT>::find(keyT &k)
{
```

and hashMap::maybeT isn't recognized ("expected a class or namespace").  Qualifying hashMap with keyT and valueT doesn't help, either.

How can I export these aliases (or typedefs, if there is a way to make that work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disambiguate the dependent name:

```
template <typename keyT, typename valueT>
typename hashMap<keyT, valueT>::maybeT hashMap<keyT,valueT>::find(keyT &k)
// ^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

(Since you're writing a template, you might as well keep everything inline, though, and cut down on the code noise. Otherwise you should add `inline` to the member function declaration.)

Comment: Ah!  Thanks.  I was trying the wrong disambiguation:  typename hashMap<typename keyT, typename valueT>::maybeT